# How to mock a method with parameters that call another method?

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I'm trying to create a test for this class to test the getLanguageLabel() method:

```
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface;

class OnlyOne {

protected $languageManager;

  public function __construct(LanguageManagerInterface $language_manager) {
    $this->languageManager = $language_manager;
  }

  public function getLanguageLabel($language) {
    switch ($language) {
      case LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED:
      case '':
        // If the language is empty then is Not specified.
        return $this->languageManager->getLanguage(LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED)->getName();

      case LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_NOT_APPLICABLE:
        return $this->languageManager->getLanguage(LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_NOT_APPLICABLE)->getName();

      default:
        return ucfirst($language);
    }
  }
```

This is the Test for the class:

```
  /**
   * @dataProvider providerGetLanguageLabel
   */
  public function testGetLanguageLabel($expected, $language_code) {
    // Language mock.
    $language = $this->createMock('Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageInterface');
    $language->expects($this->any())
      ->method('getName')
      ->willReturn($expected);

    // Language manager mock.
    $language_manager = $this->createMock('Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface');
    $language_manager->expects($this->any())
      ->method('getLanguage')
      ->with($language_code)
      ->willReturn($language);

    // Creating the object
    $only_one = new OnlyOne($language_manager);
    // Testing the function.
    $this->assertEquals($expected, $only_one->getLanguageLabel($language_code));
  }

  /**
   * Data provider for testGetLanguageLabel().
   */
  public function providerGetLanguageLabel() {
    $tests['empty langcode'] = ['Not specified', ''];
    // LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED == 'und'
    $tests['und langcode'] = ['Not specified', LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED];
    // LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_NOT_APPLICABLE == 'zxx'
    $tests['zxx langcode'] = ['Not applicable', LanguageInterface::LANGCODE_NOT_APPLICABLE];
    $tests['es langcode'] = ['Es', 'es'];
    $tests['en langcode'] = ['En', 'en'];

    return $tests;
  }
```

But it seems that I'm doing in the correct way the mocking of the getLanguage() method because I'm getting this error:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Drupal\Tests\onlyone\Unit\OnlyOneTest::testGetLanguageLabel with data set "empty langcode" ('Not specified', '')
Expectation failed for method name is equal to "getLanguage" when invoked zero or more times
Parameter 0 for invocation Drupal\Core\Language\LanguageManagerInterface::getLanguage('und') does not match expected value.
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-''
+'und'
```

How I can mock correctly the getLanguage() method?

Comment: What are the constants' values? Also, `OnlyOne` seems to have a different constructor to what you've shown, is that for shortness' sake?

Comment: have you looked into [**`PHAKE`**](https://github.com/mlively/Phake)

Comment: @ishegg I edited the constructor and I added the constants values

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam thanks but I prefer don't use it because the code needs to run in an environment where PHAKE will not be available.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer ok, guess i am sorry for that didnt knew,

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam no problem at least I know now that this exists :-) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your test doesn't reflect the behavior of your production code.

For the "empty langcode" data set, you expect `LanguageManager::getLanguage()` to be called with the empty sting.  But in the production code, if `OnlyOne::getLanguageLabel()` is passed the empty string, it calls `LanguageManager::getLanguage()` with LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED.  You can see this in the error message - it's expecting `''`, but it's getting `'und'`, which the comment says is the value of LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED.

To make this test work, when `OnlyOne::getLanguageLabel()` is passed the empty string you would have to expect `LanguageManager::getLanguage()` will be passed LANGCODE_NOT_SPECIFIED.  To make this work with your existing structure, you'd need to modify your data provider - the value you pass to `getLanguageLabel()` will not necessarily be the same one that is passed to `getLanguage()`.  Alternatively, since this is a special case, you might remove this data set from the data provider and make this it's own test.

Comment: Thanks. Do you think that is a good idea add a conditional to handle this problem before the mock of the getLanguage method?

Comment: I would not add a conditional to the test.  As a rule, the logic of your tests should be as simple as possible.  That helps prevent bugs getting into your test code.  If you have a special case, it should probably have its own test.  That keeps the tests simpler and makes the special cases stand out as special.